Android Google Chrome Disconnecting Sockets
We have a website that uses sockets. Whenever users leave the webpage for another app or close the screen, it will usually disconnect the WebSocket. The error is very vague, and this seems to be a problem where Android likes to do this to conserve battery life/resources. Websites don't have much control over this. What is the solution to fix this and the cause of this? Thanks!
I have tried on multiple devices and we have consistently been able to recreate it when we leave the app and come back to the webpage. This seems to consistently cause the Android disconnect.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

We should ensure that our WebSocket client can automatically reconnect when the connection is lost. Here is a basic example in JavaScript:
let socket;
const reconnectInterval = 5000; // 5 seconds

function connect() {
  socket = new WebSocket('wss://yourserver.com/path');

  socket.onopen = () => {
    console.log('WebSocket is open now.');
  };

  socket.onclose = () => {
    console.log(`WebSocket is closed now. Reconnecting in ${reconnectInterval / 1000} seconds...`);
    setTimeout(connect, reconnectInterval);
  };

  socket.onerror = (error) => {
    console.error('WebSocket error observed:', error);
  };

  socket.onmessage = (event) => {
    console.log('Message from server', event.data);
  };
}

// Start the connection
connect();

Read that for get more information about that.

WebSocket API - MDN Web Docs
Page Visibility API - MDN Web Docs
Using WebSockets - HTML5 Rocks
Service Workers and WebSockets (Demo on using Service Workers for push notifications and background tasks)

